# Как заставить работать 3G модем E3372 в Kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: linux, kubuntu, модемы

Есть ОС Kubuntu 15.04 и Windows 7 на одном компе.
В Windows модем прекрасно работает, а в Kubuntu отказывается соединятся.
Создавал "Мобильное" соединение. Предыдущий модем(3G) работал нормально.
При попытке изменить созданное соединение происходит краш редактора соединений.
При попытке подключения зависает на "Получение сетевого адреса". Вопрос: Как заставить работать этот модем?
P.S. Сидиром и карта, и сам модем определяются нормально. В lsusb он есть.
Вывод lsusb

```
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x12d1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
  idProduct          0x1506 E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
  bcdDevice            1.02
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          221
    bNumInterfaces          5
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 
      bInterfaceProtocol     18 
      iInterface              0 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  04 24 02 02
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 01 00 00
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 00 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  04 24 02 02
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 01 00 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 00 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x000a  1x 10 bytes
        bInterval               9
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 
      bInterfaceProtocol     22 
      iInterface              8 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  06 24 1a 00 01 1f
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  0d 24 0f 0a 0f 00 00 00 ea 05 03 00 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 02 02
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               5
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 
      bInterfaceProtocol     22 
      iInterface              9 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               5
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        4
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x88  EP 8 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
вывод dmesg
    [  477.584249] usb 1-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  477.689009] usb 1-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1506
[  477.689017] usb 1-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  477.689022] usb 1-2.4: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[  477.689026] usb 1-2.4: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[  477.690681] option 1-2.4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  477.690847] usb 1-2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  477.691019] option 1-2.4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  477.691158] usb 1-2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  477.693697] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2.4:1.2: MAC-Address: 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  477.693705] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2.4:1.2: setting rx_max = 16384
[  477.693975] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2.4:1.2: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[  477.694525] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2.4:1.2 wwan0: register 'huawei_cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4, Huawei CDC NCM device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  477.695041] usb-storage 1-2.4:1.3: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  477.695162] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-2.4:1.3
[  477.695526] usb-storage 1-2.4:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  477.695617] scsi host9: usb-storage 1-2.4:1.4
[  478.692357] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  478.692415] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  478.693379] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[  478.695619] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  478.696858] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[  478.697348] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  478.700420] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  478.722241] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  478.722251] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[  478.722257] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  478.722260] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[  478.722263] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 91 fe 00 00 02 00
[  478.722281] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr0, sector 149496
[  478.722629] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  478.722634] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[  478.722638] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  478.722641] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[  478.722644] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 91 fe 00 00 02 00
[  478.722658] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr0, sector 149496
[  478.722663] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 18687, async page read
[  478.778839] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  478.778846] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[  478.778850] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  478.778853] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[  478.778855] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 91 fc 00 00 02 00
[  478.778867] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr0, sector 149488
[  478.779211] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  478.779215] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[  478.779218] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  478.779221] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[  478.779222] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 91 fc 00 00 02 00
[  478.779233] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr0, sector 149488
[  478.779236] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 18686, async page read
[  487.830183] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2.4:1.2 wwan0: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[  487.830746] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2.4:1.2 wwan0: kevent 12 may have been dropped
```

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос те строки, что добавляются  в вывод программы `dmesg` после подключения вашего *usb*-устройства.

Comment: и `lsusb -v` (только ту секцию что про модем)

Comment: Добавил в первый пост

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[  478.700420] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  478.722241] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  478.722251] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[  478.722257] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  478.722260] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[  478.722263] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 91 fe 00 00 02 00
[  478.722281] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr0, sector 149496
```

Эта ошибка связана с CD модема, который в Linux обычно не используется. Попробуйте переключить устройство в режим "только модем"

http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=264526.0